# Nested Async Await is not yielding proper result

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, flutterflow

I have a Firestore structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhBOL.png)
what i want is i want to get count of all the members that are enrolled within a user. But Recursive call to below function is just counting the initial array count.

```dart
Future<int> getalldata(String docref) async {
    int count = 0, abhj = 0;
    DocumentReference docRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('memberships').doc(docref);

    DocumentSnapshot value = await docRef.get();
    print(value.data().toString());
    if (value.data().toString().contains('referredto:')) {
      print("CHala");
      if (value.get('referredto').length > 0) {
        print(value.get('referredto').length);

        for (dynamic i in value.get('referredto')) {
          count += await getalldata(i.id.toString());
        }

        //print('its empty' + value.get('referredto')[0].id.toString())
      } else {
        count = await count + 1;
        print('ye b1');
      }
    } else {
      count = await count + 1;
      print('ye b');
    }

    print("count>>" + count.toString());
    return await count;
  }
```

I want recursive function which can count all the memberships. But i am getting just the count in the initial Call.

Comment: 1. You are `await`ing various things that aren't `Future`s (e.g. `await count`).  Enable the [`unawaited_futures`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#unawaited_futures) and [`await_only_futures`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#await_only_futures) lints instead of just sprinkling `await` everywhere. 2. What printed output do you get?  Are you sure that your recursive function is executing the code paths you expect? 3. If an a value includes a `referredto` list, you currently are counting only the children but not the parent itself.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: I suggest you work with Firebase Cloud Functions and listen to CRUD operations. Then you can easily update count for whatever you want using `FieldValue.increment`